# SPSS Python - fast(er) way of accessing Value Labels

Tags: python, spss

I am trying to pull the variables' names, labels and value labels. I noticed that all assignments are quite fast, except the one referencing the `ValueLabels`. On my test dataset, if I comment out that line, everything else takes about 1 second. But that line alone delays the whole code by about 15 seconds, and the test dataset is not a large one (by my standards at least :))

Is this something inherent with accessing the variable dictionary ? Or is there another, faster, way of pulling the whole dictionary, without going variable by variable...?

```
begin program.

import spss
import spssaux

vardict = spssaux.VariableDict()

var_list=[]
var_values={}
var_type={}
var_labels={}

for i in range(spss.GetVariableCount()):
    var=spss.GetVariableName(i)
    var_list.append(var)

    #this is the line causing the massive delay
    var_values[var]=vardict[i].ValueLabels

    var_type[var]=str(spss.GetVariableFormat(i)[0])
    var_labels[var]=vardict[i].VariableLabel
```

`end program.`

In fact I only need it to check if a variable had value labels defined or not. But I have no idea how to check that in any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that using the `spssaux` module was the culprit here. I have no idea why, because pretty much all the Internet knowledge points to that way of getting the value labels.

However, almost by accident I stumbled upon the help of the `spss' module, which states:

> ```
>  |  valueLabels
>  |      Get, set or delete value labels. The set of value labels for a particular variable is represented
>  |      as a Python dictionary whose keys are the values for which labels are being set and whose
>  |      values are the associated labels. Labels must be specified as quoted strings.
>  |
>  |         --examples
>  |         # Get all value labels for a specified variable
>  |         import spss
>  |         spss.StartDataStep()
>  |         datasetObj = spss.Dataset()
>  |         varObj = datasetObj.varlist['minority']
>  |         vallabels = varObj.valueLabels
>  |         spss.EndDataStep()
> ```

As I was only interested to see if variables have (or do not have) value labels, I created a dictionary storing the length of the valueLabels dictionary of each variable:

```
begin program.
# Get all value labels for a specified variable
import spss
spss.StartDataStep()
datasetObj = spss.Dataset()

var_labels={}
for var in datasetObj.varlist:
    var_labels[var.name]=len(var.valueLabels)

spss.EndDataStep()

print var_labels

end program.
```

It is instantaneous, even on large files. (I admit, what "large" means may be different from user to user; I stopped the code in the OP after 30 minutes on a "large" file, as it was obviously not being time-effective).